# C# Custom TypeConverter in class library project

Tags: c#, class-library, typeconverter

I have created my `TypeConverter` for enum localization, registered it to `MyEnum` type using `[TypeConverter(typeof(MyEnum))]` and it works well in my Windows Forms Application project.

But now I need to use that same converter in Class Library project, and suddenly my `TypeConverter` class does not get instantiated at all. Is there any step or setting I am missing to get `[TypeConverter]` attribute working in Class Libary project? Thank you.

Comment: Any exceptions or errors that may be useful?

Comment: I wish there were any. I only figured out that TypeConverter is not instantiated at all :(

Comment: Are they targeting the same .Net Framework version?

Comment: Yes, .NET 4.0 both...

Answer (score 1):

It could be something to do with the converter not being found in the assembly?

[Why is this TypeConverter not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612909/why-is-this-typeconverter-not-working?rq=1)