# TypeDescriptor.GetConverter() doesnt return my converter

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, typedescriptor

I have a simple type with a custom type converter that is compiled and loaded at runtime. TypeDescriptor.GetConverter() doesn't find the right converter though. Here is a stand-alone example

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

public class Program
{
    private static string src =
@"
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace LoadMe
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(FooConverter))]
    public class Foo
    {
    }
    public class FooConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        // stuff
    }
}
";
    public static void Main()
    {
        var codeProvider        = new CSharpCodeProvider(new     Dictionary<string, string>{{ "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" }});
        var compileParameters   = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "System.dll"     }) { GenerateInMemory = true };
        var compilerResults     = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compileParameters, src);

        if (compilerResults.Errors.Count == 0)
        {
            var fooType = compilerResults.CompiledAssembly.GetType("LoadMe.Foo");
            Console.WriteLine(fooType.FullName + "::" + fooType.Assembly.FullName);
            Console.WriteLine("Type converter type = '" + TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(fooType).GetType().FullName + "'");
        }
        else 
        {
            foreach (var err in compilerResults.Errors)
                Console.WriteLine(err);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output of the example (compiled in vs)

```
LoadMe.Foo::q5sszdls, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Type converter type = 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter'
```

Should I just dig out the attribute and create the instance myself, or am I missing something else here?

ALSO odd! When ran in LINQPad as a 'C# program', it actually works! here is the output. [LINQPad ready source](https://gist.github.com/dogglesfan/b5d7bf4332b4d400167c)

```
LoadMe.Foo::oqmid5in, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Type converter type = 'LoadMe.FooConverter'
```

Any idea what LINQPad actually does differently to have it find the right converter?

Comment: It's supposed to work like that, and [a quick online test](http://ideone.com/16utE6) shows that it does. Can you post a minimal complete program that demonstrates the behaviour you describe?

Comment: hmm, the types are compiled at runtime so that must be the cause. will whip up an isolated example

Comment: I just edited it to be a standalone example, forgot an edit comment :O

Comment: Have a look at the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7052397/2455604 - we used it and it worked very nicely by just hooking up another AssemblyResolver.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

.NET uses reflection to load the specified type converter. When you pass a `Type` instance to `TypeConverterAttribute`, your `TypeConverterAttribute` will contain an assembly-qualified type name. Loading that assembly-qualified type name does not work, because the assembly cannot be found. (Yes, even though that assembly is already loaded.)

You can use the constructor overload that takes a string to specify the type name without any references to the defining assembly, in which case it will be looked up in the same assembly as the type whose converter you're requesting:

```
[TypeConverter("LoadMe.FooConverter")]
public class Foo
{
}
```

Comment: Note: You can also add type converters at run time using TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes. This is useful if you cannot modify the type e.g. because it is a .NET framework type.

Comment: I'm such an idiot, I was already using this concept elsewhere for property grid editors but it totally evaded me

Comment: This answer was extremely helpful. For reference, I had to use the fully qualified namespace in place of "LoadMe" for it to work.

Comment: @DaveInCaz Yes. `LoadMe` is the fully qualified namespace the OP used.